# trying to import data from a website into pandas

Tags: arrays, json, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to import data from a json website into a pandas dataframe, I can download the data but am unsure how to export it into pandas. At the moment im just getting some information into the table which relates to the last record on the webpage, below is the code I'm using. In the future I want to add more columns and data to the dataframe from the website, but at the moment if you can help with the one column, I will try and work the rest out for myself. Any help much appreciated.

```
import requests
import json
headers = {'User-Agent':
       'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}
url = 'https://api.gbgb.org.uk/api/results/meeting/355352&?meeting=355352&'
response =requests.get(url,headers=headers)
data=json.loads(response.text)

def jprint(obj):
    # create a formatted string of the Python JSON object
    text = json.dumps(obj, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
    #print(text)

jprint(response.json())

#print(response.json())

for d in data[0]['races']:
    for dog in d['traps']:
        print(dog['dogName'])



import pandas as pd
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'dogName': dog})
print(test_df.info())
test_df
```

Comment: quite as as simple as `df.to_csv('filename.csv')` you'll need to set your directory too.

Comment: Hi thanks but that doesn't save what i want, as I explained in the original question the data it saves is just the last record of the page, I need the forty dogs being saved that are listed in the for loop above in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a dictionary from the dog names and append each dictionary to a list.
From that list you can then create your dataframe.

```
dog_name_list = []     #You will add a dictionary with the column name and dog name to this list.
for d in data[0]['races']:
    for dog in d['traps']:
        dog_name = dog["dogName"]
        dog_name_list.append({"dogName":dog_name})


test_df = pd.DataFrame(dog_name_list)
print(test_df.info())
print(test_df)
```

Your for loop is just looping through the data and printing the dog names. As a result of this when you try to create a dataframe with the variable dog it returns the json response of the last dog in the data "Weight For Jay".

As an FYI it is also good practice to put all of your imports at the beginning of your code.

Comment: Hi RamWill, many thanks for your help and advise with this, much appreciated.